# Where should I place a download tarball?

Tags: linux, installation

I downloaded ChromePlus tarball and extracted it to my home directory. The extracted folder contains an executable that I can double-click to launch ChromePlus. So I assume I do not need to any extra things to install it.

I'm new to Linux. Where should I place ChromePlus directory? It's currently sitting on my home directory and it does not look neat. After googling, I thought about /bin/, /usr/bin, /usr/lib. Where is the best place?

Comment: I think you better ask this question on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do so. I put the extracted directory to /usr/local and make a link to the binary in /usr/local/bin, so it looks something like:

/usr/local/bin/theapp -> /usr/local/Theapp/bin/theapp

If I care about upgrading Theapp and the extracted directory contains version then I also symlink "Theapp" to point to current version of it, e. g.:

/usr/local/Theapp -> /usr/local/Theapp-1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Since /usr/local may not be writable on some systems that you have access to, one's home directory is often the only place. For things like compiling the Linux kernel source code, using /usr/src, a path outside a home dir, is even discouraged.